Cannot display own 3D model with react native expo go
I have a problem displaying my own 3D model with expo go react native using my android phone.
This is the code in question:
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Canvas, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Box } from "@react-three/drei";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";
export default function App() {
  const chairModel = useLoader(
    OBJLoader,
    require("Mappet/app/assets/3D/chair.obj")
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Title</Text>
      <Canvas>
        <mesh>
          <boxGeometry args={[2, 2, 1]} />
          {chairModel && <primitive object={chairModel.scene} />}
          <meshStandardMaterial color={"blue"} />
        </mesh>
        <ambientLight />
      </Canvas>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
});


Trying to run this code gives an error where expo cannot find the file:
Android Bundling failed 13908ms (C:\Users\XXX\MyFolder\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js) Unable to resolve "Myfolder/app/assets/3D/chair.obj" from "app\components\thisfile.js"
I've moved the file around everywhere to make sure it has the right path (even asked chatGPT), converted it from obj to gltf and tried that, and even downloaded a new model online just to be 100% sure it's not the model itself being corrupt. I still get the same error. I even used require() but to no avail. Loading the boxGeometry works fine though.
I have tried several tutorials online, and most encourage me to make and edit the metro.config.js file, but whenever I create a metro.config.js and edit it accordingly, I can no longer load my application due to this error:
error: node_modules\expo-router\_ctx.android.js: C:\Users\XXX\MyFolder\node_modules\expo-router\_ctx.android.js: Expected `fromDir` to be of type `string`, got `undefined
Updating or reinstalling expo-router doesn't fix the problem.
My metro.config.js looks like this:

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ["js", "jsx", "json", "ts", "tsx", "cjs"],
    assetExts: ["glb", "gltf", "mtl", "obj", "png", "jpg"],
  },
  transformer: {
    unstable_allowRequireContext: true,
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);

This is my package.json:
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.24.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.81",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.105.5",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.16.3",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",
    "expo-device": "~5.9.4",
    "expo-gl": "^13.6.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.10.6",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.7.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.5.5",
    "expo-router": "^3.4.10",
    "expo-sensors": "~12.9.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-3d-model-view": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-maps": "1.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-zip-archive": "^6.1.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "three": "^0.164.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.10"
  },
  "private": true
}

First question on stack, all help appreciated
